# Laravel Model append attribute from polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I have a model `Course` as follows:

```
class Course extends Model {
    protected $table = 'courses';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = true;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $appends = ['locked_by'];

    public function lock(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Lock', 'asset');
    }

    public function getLockedByAttribute(){
        if($this->lock->count()){
            return $this->lock->shift()->owner_id;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

A `Course` can have many associated `Lock` objects indicating that a user wants to lock the `Course` data for editing by other users.

Now, when retrieving the `Course` details of a specific course from the Laravel API I get the following data:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Linear Algebra 2",
        "abbreviation": "2WF20",
        "status": "draft",
        "owner_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2020-03-10 13:09:15",
        "locked_by": 2,
        "lock": []
    }
```

while I expected:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Linear Algebra 2",
        "abbreviation": "2WF20",
        "status": "draft",
        "owner_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2020-03-10 13:09:15",
        "locked_by": 2
    }
```

As you can see in the code the `"locked_by"` attribute does not come from the `Course` table but is added by the `$appends` variable in the model. The number that's after `"locked_by"` is the user ID of the user currently owning the lock on this `Course`.

Can anyone tell me where the `"lock": []` attribute comes from and how to get rid of it? I noticed myself that `"lock": []` attribute is not there if the `getLockedByAttribute()` function does not access `$this->lock`, however, I need this reference to get the `user_id` of the user owning the lock? Am I doing something wrong? Should I use a different approach to get the `user_id` of the user owning the lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lock` attribute is in the response because in order to get the value for the `locked_by` attribute the model needs to load the `lock` relationship.

If you want to hide the lock relationship every time you return the `Course` model as an array or JSON you can add the relationship to the `$hidden` property on your `Course` model.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json):

> Sometimes you may wish to limit the attributes, such as passwords,
>   that are included in your model's array or JSON representation. To do
>   so, add a $hidden property to your model.
>
> When hiding relationships, use the relationship's method name.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['lock'];
}
```

If you only want to hide it in a specific request you could do something like this:

```
return App\Courses::with('lock')
    ->get()
    ->makeHidden('lock');
```